# Windows Server 2003, file downloads

Tags: windows, security, internet-explorer, windows-server-2003

I'm having problems downloading a file to a Windows Server 2003 machine. The file is of type .msi. When visiting the page I get the following message:

```
Internet Explorer cannot download <filename> from <host>.

Internet Explorer was not able to open this Internet site.  The requested site is    either unavailable or cannot be found.  Please try again later.
```

Here's some details:

- The file is signed with a certificate I trust.
- Internet Explorer Enhanced Security Configuration is enabled
- The site I'm downloading from is added to the list of Trusted sites.
- In the Internet Options, I've selected the following options under Trusted Sites - Custom Level:

  - Automatic prompting for file downloads: Enable
  - File download: Enable
  - Launching applications and unsafe files: Prompt
- The site uses https

If I uninstall "Internet Explorer Enhanced Security Configuration", the problem goes away. But I don't want to do this.

Any ideas? Is there some option I've missed?